# How do you get a list of the names of all files present in a web server directory using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, server, directory, backend

when using *fs.readdir* it gives me file name present in the given path but how can get file name stored on a specific path on a web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using this function

```
fs.readdir ('../', function (err, data) {
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
else console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

To access the

- root(or C drive) use `/` .
- current directory use `./`.
- parent directory use `../`.
- parent of parent directory use `../../`.
- To access a directory in the parent directory use `../sibling_name`.

Now I believe you can navigate through directories. Navigate through directories and list the files and the folders contained in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help u.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
function getFile(dirPath) {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
    files.forEach(function (item) {
        const currentPath = path.join(dirPath, item),
        isFile = fs.statSync(currentPath).isFile(),
        isDir = fs.statSync(currentPath).isDirectory();
        if (isFile) {
            // console.log(currentPath);
        } else if (isDir) {
           console.log(currentPath);
           getFile(currentPath);
        }
    });
}

getFile('./'); // this is your server path
```